# Update 'list' based on user input only updating once

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to create a very basic tic tac toe game that takes a user input, and depending on that input, places either an x or o down in the index of that input. I'm relatively new to python so I'm trying not to google the answer but really break each step down.

```
#Create Board
row1 = ['', '', '']
row2 = ['', '', '']
row3 = ['', '', '']
def display(x,y,z):
    print(x)
    print(y)
    print(z)

show_board = display(row1,row2,row3)

#Get user input
def userChoice():
    choice = int(input('Pick a number 1-9! '))
    while choice > 9 or choice < 1:
        print('Please pick a number 1-9!')
        choice = int(input('Pick a number 1-9! '))
    return choice

#Place the marker onto the board
def placeMarker():
    if position >= 1 and position < 4:
        row1[position] = marker
    elif position >= 4 and position < 7:
        row2[position] = marker
    else:
        row3[position] = marker
        
#Start the game        
def startGame():
    clear_output()
    marker = input('x or o? ').lower()
#   while marker != 'x' or marker != 'o':
#       marker = input('x or o?').lower()
    display(row1,row2,row3)
    while(True):
        userChoice()
        placeMarker()
        display(row1,row2,row3)
```

I created a function to place the marker down and it does so on the first attempt, but any further attempt wont update the board. I feel like it's an issue with my placeMarker() function but can't really hit the nail on the head here. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code should be getting errors if you ever call `startGame()`, because you reference undefined variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`placeMarker()` is not correct. First of all, list indexes start at `0`, not `1`, so you need to subtract `1` from `position` to get a valid index. So any value of `position` other than `1` or `2` would get an `IndexError`.

In addition, it's wrong when the position is in `row2` or `row3`, because you need to adjust the position down from a higher number to the `0-2` range.

You also have no code that ever sets `position`, and `marker` is a local variable in `startGame()`. You need to add more function returns and parameters.

Finally, you need to call `startGame()` to get everything going.

```
#Create Board
row1 = ['', '', '']
row2 = ['', '', '']
row3 = ['', '', '']
def display(x,y,z):
    print(x)
    print(y)
    print(z)

show_board = display(row1,row2,row3)

#Get user input
def userChoice():
    choice = int(input('Pick a number 1-9! '))
    while choice > 9 or choice < 1:
        print('Please pick a number 1-9!')
        choice = int(input('Pick a number 1-9! '))
    return choice

#Place the marker onto the board
def placeMarker(position, marker):
    if position < 4:
        row1[position-1] = marker
    elif position < 7:
        row2[position-4] = marker
    else:
        row3[position-7] = marker
        
#Start the game        
def startGame():
    clear_output()
    marker = input('x or o? ').lower()
#   while marker != 'x' or marker != 'o':
#       marker = input('x or o?').lower()
    display(row1,row2,row3)
    while(True):
        position = userChoice()
        placeMarker(position, marker)
        display(row1,row2,row3)

startGame()
```

Comment: So i actually called it on a separate line (was using jupyter notebooks) My issue mainly was that when i place an x down, it places it where i want once, and after that if i pick a different spot, it doesnt place it and just shows the first spot i picked as marked. But i will go ahead and try this code. Thank you so so much.

Answer (score 1):

You only defined the function `startGame` but you did not called it.

Add `startGame()` at the end of the program to call the function.

*Note* : the "first attempt" is done when you create the variable show_board

Comment: `show_board()` doesn't place the first marker. He must have just left out the call.

Comment: It does not place the marker but displays the board. That's how I understood when he said "I created a function to place the marker down and it does so on the first attempt, but any further attempt wont update the board".
But I agree which your answer for the placeMarker that is wrong

Comment: Now I suspect you're right that he never calls it, since it would get an error when trying to place the marker.